# Prove that $f(x)/x$ is increasing

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose $f(0)<0$ and that for all $x$, $f’’(x)>0$. Show that $f(x)/x$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

I tried to use the Taylor formula but it didn’t work. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match with the one in the body of the question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks for reminding me

Comment: @Bernard sorry I made a mistake in my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\frac {f(x)} x)'=\frac {xf'(x)-f(x)} {x^{2}}$ so it is enough to show that $xf'(x)-f(x) > 0$. Now $(xf'(x)-f(x))'=xf''(x) > 0$ so $xf'(x)-f(x)$ is increasing and it is enough to observe that $0f'(0)-f(0)>0$.